# Python data clean in adjacent columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe where some of the values in the 'Type' column are incorrect:

| ID | Type | Other Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 10.0 | 56 |
| ABC | 10.0 | 34 |
| ABC | 0.0 | 78 |
| DEF | 20.0 | 45 |
| DEF | 0.0 | 23 |
| ZWS | 20.0 | 99 |
| TYH | 10.0 | 12 |
| TYH | 10.0 | 63 |
| FCE | 0.0 | 56 |
| FCE | 20.0 | 78 |
| XSA | 10.0 | 74 |
| RED | 0.0 | 55 |
| QWA | 20.0 | 74 |

I would like to go through each ID and identify if the Type is equal to 0.0, then replace it with a value from the a row where the same id has a value other than 0.0.
If there is no other row with the ID, and it is 0.0 in the type column then change it to Nan, or 99 so it can be removed later.

The outcome would be:
ABC on 3rd row changes to 10.0
DEF on 5th row changes to 20.0
FCE on 9th row changes to 20.0
RED on 12th row changes to Nan or 99 as no equivalent match found.

What would be the best approach for this problem?

I have tried building dictionary and looping, but I keep getting stuck at the replace 0.0 for values of equivalent key.

Comment: You can do this with a left join/merge.

Comment: What if there are multiple rows with the same ID and different Type?

Comment: The answer by Corralien solves the problem - its a great answer.
It doesn't take into account the scenario of different types, but in this scenario, there is only a real value or an error value; The challenge was to resolve the errors to the other 'correct' type.

Comment: We still prefer that posters show what they tried. We're here to help you fix your code, not do the whole thing for you.

Comment: Hi Bramar, thank you for your comment, yes I was ashamed not to paste the code, but I'd tried many things and didn't have the correct strategy, I needed the mask idea - i had a dictionary with the data, just couldn't figure out how to apply it to the whole dataset without a loop - which wasn't practical on the data size. Thanks for pulling me up - I will endeavour to get code samples up as much as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask to hide rows equal to 0 then group by `Type` and broadcast the max value (any other value than `NaN`) to all rows:

```
m = df['Type'].eq(0)  # boolean mask
df['New Type'] = df['Type'].mask(m).groupby(df['ID']).transform('max')
print(df)

# Output
     ID  Type  Other Data  New Type
0   ABC  10.0          56      10.0
1   ABC  10.0          34      10.0
2   ABC   0.0          78      10.0  # 0.0 -> 10.0
3   DEF  20.0          45      20.0
4   DEF   0.0          23      20.0  # 0.0 -> 20.0
5   ZWS  20.0          99      20.0
6   TYH  10.0          12      10.0
7   TYH  10.0          63      10.0
8   FCE   0.0          56      20.0  # 0.0 -> 20.0
9   FCE  20.0          78      20.0
10  XSA  10.0          74      10.0
11  RED   0.0          55       NaN  # 0.0 -> NaN
12  QWA  20.0          74      20.0
```

Comment: this is worked perfect. Generated a whole new set of ideas using masks. Thank you.